# jQuery to replace contents of a <li>

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I have a link that wired up to a jQuery function. It is inside an `<li>` with another link.  Code here:

```
<li id="aps_pdf1">
   <a target="_blank"" href="....">1testpdf.pdf</a>
      <span style="padding-left:40px">
           <a id="delete-aps_pdf1" class="delete_pdf" title="Delete this PDF." href="#">Delete</a>
      </span>
</li>
```

I'm trying to replace the first link with a file upload control when the `delete-aps_pdf1` is clicked by replacing the html with jQuery.  Here's what I have so far with my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.delete_pdf').each(function(i,e) { //grab the link class delete-pdf
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/delete-/, '');
        var li = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
        $(this).click(function(){
            //alert('Clicked! '+ id);//$(this).attr('id'));  //THIS WORKS WHEN CLICKED
            //alert(li);
            $(li).replaceWith('<input type="file" style="width: 700px;" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" />');

        });
    });
```

My replaceWith doesn't seem to be working at all.  I'm relatively new with jquery and I've done this reading documentation so I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere.

A step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to replace a string. Pass the jQuery object instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.delete_pdf').each(function(i,e) { //grab the link class delete-pdf
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/delete-/, '');
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    $(this).click(function(){
        //alert('Clicked! '+ id);//$(this).attr('id'));  //THIS WORKS WHEN CLICKED
        //alert(li);
        $(li).replaceWith('<input type="file" style="width: 700px;" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" />');

    });
});
```

Comment: Ahhh I see! I was grabbing the ID as a string and not the actual element.  This makes perfect sense and worked!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the li id (.attr("id")) which means that you need to concatenate a # on the front of your other query

```
$('#'+li).replaceWith('<input type="file" style="width: 700px;" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" />');
```

Comment: or you could do as Michael Berkompas stated (which basically means you get a reference to the actual DOM element stored in li which means you can just do $(li).replaceWith or probably just li.replaceWith

Answer (score 0):

Could you just grab the parent li with:

```
var li = $(this).parent('li');
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, it would return `[object Object]`.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm grabbing the object, not the ID, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the following line

```
var li = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
```

It should be

```
var li = $(this).closest('li');
```

or

```
var li = $(this).closest('li#' + id);
```